# Python Coverage how to generate Unittest report

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage

In python I can get test coverage by `coverage run -m unittest` and the do `coverage report -m` / `coverage html` to get `html` report.
However, it does not show the actual unit test report. The unit test result is in the logs, but I would like to capture it in a `xml` or `html`, so I can integrate it with `Jenkins` and publish on each build. This way user does not have to dig into logs.

I tried to find solution to this but could not find any, please let me know, how we can get this using coverage tool.

I can get this using nose2 - `nose2 --html-report --with-coverage --coverage-report html` - this will generate two html report - one for unit test and other for coverage. But for some reason this fails when I run with actual project (no coverage data collected / reported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for those who end up here , I solved it with -
`nose2 --html-report --with-coverage --coverage-report html --coverage ./`

The issue I was having earlier with 'no coverage data' was fixed by specifying the the directory where the coverage should be reported, in the command above its with `--coverage ./`